# Creating a spreadsheet using textboxes only

Tags: c#, textbox, spreadsheet

My assignment states that I have to create a spreadsheet.

Using a grid of textboxes 26x26.

However, I am already stumped as online you can only find spreadsheet related things by importing from excel or databases.

I can only use textboxes, not even data grid view.

26x26 means around 676 cells (excluding columns and rows. IE. Columns A B C D E etc and Rows 1 2 3 4 5 etc.)

any help on how to do any of this. I have no idea.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not code writing service site. What did you try? What do have?
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate textboxes in simple loop and add them to your form programmatically.
Example using winforms:

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 26; j++)
            {
                var txt = new TextBox()
                {
                    Name = $"textBox{i}{j}",
                    Width = 50,
                    Height = 20,
                    Location = new Point(50 * j, 20 * i)
                };
                this.Controls.Add(txt); //Add new TextBox to your form's controls
            }
        }
    }
```

Note Width, Height and Location properties to fit them without overlapping each other.